# What is the minimal requirement to fulfill the mitzvah of reading Shema?

Tags: zemanim, shema

About a week ago, I saw in a siddur (might have been Koren) an instruction above [the 1st Shema said as part of *Birkot Hashachar*](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Siddur_Sefard%2C_Weekday_Shacharit%2C_Morning_Prayer.12?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) stating that one should recite the 1st paragraph *Ve'ahavta* at this point if one feels that he will not be able to recite all 3 paragraphs before the time deadline for the morning Shema.

This had me thinking - does one fulfill the mitzvah of Shema by just reciting the first paragraph? Can he do this *lechatchila*? E.g. - he arises early in the morning, says the 1st paragraph and goes to sleep and when he awakens it is past the deadline?

Likewise for the night time Shema - he didn't say it earlier in the night, he awakens, says 1 paragraph, falls asleep and when he awakens, it's daytime.

If, in fact, the mitzvah can be fulfilled by just 1 paragraph then whey do we need to say the other 2?

Comment: @WAF I appreciate the edited link. Perhaps, I should have specified that I saw this in a Nusach Ashkenaz siddur. From what I've seen, Nusach Sefard tends to have the full first paragraph, whereas most Ashkenaz siddurim do not. Some do. It doesn't affect the link that you did, though; It's useful.

Answer (score 4):

From the language of the Rambam (MT [Kriat Shema 1:2](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/912952/jewish/Kriat-Shema-Chapter-One.htm)) one sees he held the mitzva is to recite the three paragraphs. In a long list of "what if you made this mistake" in [chapter 2](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/912953/jewish/Kriat-Shema-Chapter-Two.htm), at no point does the Rambam considers that anything less than 3 paragraphs counts to fulfill the *mitzva*.

The Shulchan Aruch ([OC 60:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.60.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) writes that one needs to have *kavana* (intention) during the first verse for the *mitsva* to be valid and, at a minimum, needs to read the three paragraphs.

The Rishonim debate whether the reading is a *mitzva d'orayta* or *d'rabannan* or a fulfillment of the *mitzva* to remember the exodus from Egypt (for the third paragraph). See [here](http://israel.aish.com/smicha/RavCableSugyos/HilchosKriasShema/Review%20Sheet%20for%20the%20Essential%20Chiuv%20to%20say%20Krias%20Shema%20(Sim.doc) for a digest of sources.

I have now seen that R Daniel Mann adresses this question in a [comprehensive answer](https://eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=4&cat=7&newsletter=1037&article=3930).

Answer (score 1):

The siddur means you should recite the first paragraph now, to fulfill the Torah-ordained part of the mitzvah, which has a strict time frame that is easy to miss. Then you will, of course, recite the full 3 paragraphs when you get to them, to fulfill the rest of the mitzvah.

Here you have a Mishnah Berurah that says that many Poskim hold that the first parsha is the Torah obligation.

(5) משנה ברורה סימן סז 
(ד) ולאחריה - אע"ג דהרבה פוסקים סוברין דפרשה ראשונה הוא מדאורייתא והשניה הוא מדרבנן ויש מן הפוסקים שסוברין דרק פסוק ראשון הוא מדאורייתא וכ"ש הברכות דלכו"ע הוא מדרבנן וספק דרבנן אינו חוזר יש לומר כך היתה התקנה שכל זמן שקורין חייב לקרות כעיקר התקנה ובברכותיה אם לא במקום שהתירו בפירוש כגון ההיא דלקמן סימן ק"ו ס"ב בהג"ה עי"ש. ולכאורה אם יודע שאמר פסוק ראשון או פרשה ראשונה [לכל אחד מן הדעות] וספק לו אם קרא השאר א"צ לחזור ולקרות מיהו בסימן ס"ד סעיף ג' וד' משמע שצריך לחזור וצ"ל דמעיקרא כן תקנו שיחזור. והיכא שהוא מסופק לו אם אמר פרשת ציצית וגם אמת ויציב צריך לחזור לכו"ע דיציאת מצרים חייבין להזכיר מדאורייתא. אך יש דיעות בזה דיש אומרים דיאמר פרשת ציצית וגם אמת ויציב דכולה חדא מילתא היא ויש אומרים דיאמר רק פרשת ציצית ויקיים בזה המצוה דאורייתא של זכירת יציאת מצרים ואמת ויציב א"צ לומר וכן הסכים השאגת ארי' וכתב עוד דאם נעשה לו ספק זה בערב שאינו יודע אם אמר פרשת ציצית וברכת אמת ואמונה חוזר ואומר אמת ואמונה וא"צ לחזור ולקרות פרשת ציצית מספק ואם ברי לו שקרא כל השלשה פרשיות ואינו מסופק לו אלא באמת ויציב שחרית או אמת ואמונה ערבית תרוייהו חד דינא שא"צ לחזור ולומר מספק דכיון שאמר פרשת ציצית לכו"ע הברכות הוא מדרבנן שכבר נזכר יציאת מצרים בפרשת ציצית:

Comment: Edited with sources.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, shmu. My Hebrew is quite good, so I can understand most of the above. But, we have numerous non-Hebrew-literate members. While you don't need to do a literal translation of the above, when you can, please summarize the main points as it relates to the answer, in English.

Comment: I now summarized the main point in English.